# Checkbox in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I see in the [docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons) that we use checkbox like that:

```
echo Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true);
```

In my case, value is boolean (0 and 1) and is linked to the next param ( isChecked )

So basically, I should do

```
<div class="checkbox-switch">
            <label>
                <?php $old = $tournament->mustPay;
                $checked = $old ? 'checked' : '';
                ?>

                {!!  Form::label('mustPay', trans('crud.pay4register'))  !!} <br/>
                {!!   Form::checkbox('mustPay', $old, $old , ['class' => 'switch', $checked , 'data-on-text'=>"Si", 'data-off-text'=>"No", "value" => "true"]) !!}

            </label>
        </div>
```

It seems very difficult to manage checkbox state without having linking between value and state.

Then I try to avoid to have

I'm spending a lot of time managing it, and get patchwork instead of an elegant solution. Is there an elegant way to do it, because I couldn't find one which fit my needs.... :(

Tx

Comment: why would the value of that checkbox change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not entirely sure what you are doing, but this might help

```
Form::hidden('mustPay', 0);
Form::checkbox('mustPay', 1, $tournament->mustPay, ['class' => 'switch', 'data-on-text'=>"Si", 'data-off-text'=>"No"]);
```

Comment: it worked! I confused the checkbox concept with Yes / No switch! Tx!

Comment: hehe, i thought it might be something like that ... all good, glad it works my friend